# Disabling access to specific directories and their contents

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf

I have a Web site that contains several Web applications. Each Web application corresponds to a subdirectory of the document root whose name starts with "Web". (For example, `/WebLulzGenerator` and `/WebInternetHateMachine` are Web applications but `/MoarHelperz` is not.)

I want that those Web applications be available only via HTTPS, so I did the following in my `httpd.conf` file:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<DirectoryMatch "^/Web[A-Za-z0-9]+">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</DirectoryMatch>

# In extra/httpd-ssl.conf, access to "^/Web[A-Za-z0-9]+"
# is reenabled, but only through HTTPS.
```

However, when I tested my configuration "http://myip/WebTest" opened correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<Directory>` maps to physical locations of resources. You should use [`<Location>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#location) or [`<LocationMatch>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#locationmatch)for locations.

```
<LocationMatch /Web.*>
   Order Allow,deny
   Deny from All
</Location>
```

Beware of the following warning from the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#location):

> <Location> sections operate completely
>   outside the filesystem. This has
>   several consequences. Most
>   importantly, <Location> directives
>   should not be used to control access
>   to filesystem locations. Since several
>   different URLs may map to the same
>   filesystem location, such access
>   controls may by circumvented.